Why is this grammar context-sensitive?

Working on: Richard Johnsonbaugh. (2018). Discrete Mathematics, 8/e (p. 607)

2. Determine whether the given grammar is context-sensitive, context-free, regular, or none of these. Provide all classifications that apply.
$T = \{a, b\}, N = \{\sigma, A, B\}$, with productions:
\begin{aligned}
    \sigma &\rightarrow A, \\
    \sigma &\rightarrow AAB, \\
    A &\rightarrow aa, \\
    B &\rightarrow b, \\
    Aa &\rightarrow ABa, \\
    Bb &\rightarrow ABb, \\
    AB &\rightarrow ABB,
\end{aligned}
and starting symbol $\sigma$.
I see the answer given in the book is context-sensitive; however, I do notice the rule:
$$Bb \rightarrow ABb$$
Following book's definition,

If every production is of the form
$ \alpha A \beta \rightarrow \alpha \delta \beta$,
where $ \alpha, \beta \in (N \cup T)^* ,  A \in N , \text{and} \ \delta \in (N \cup T)^* - \{ \lambda \} $,
we call $G$ a context-sensitive (or type 1) grammar.

$\alpha$ would be the null string, $B$ appears on both sides of the production, and $\beta$ would be $b$. However, the context is not preserved since an extra symbol appears to the left of $B$.
Is there a mistake in the book ?

$\alpha = \lambda$, $\beta = b$ and $\delta = AB$.
$\alpha B \beta = Bb$ and $\alpha \delta \beta = ABb$.
There is no problem with the definition, is there?

In other words, it's changing B to AB if b appears to the right of B
